# How can I wait for background processing to complete when using Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, background-process, sidekiq

I'm trying to test for a message that should eventually appear on a user's home page. It gets generated when a background process is run (using Sidekiq).

The test I run is:

```
...

it "should click on the training resource link and view message on home page", :driver => :poltergeist do
  visit skill_path(@skill)

  training_resource = @skill.training_resources.first

  click_link(training_resource.name)

  #*** Should wait here while background process runs and creates the message

  visit user_profile_path(@user)

  page.should have_css("h4", text: "Some training resource message")
  ...
end
```

Is there some way to recheck the user profile page (or refresh it) a few times to give Sidekiq time to process the background task? If the message hasn't appeared yet, maybe I can revisit the page?

This is not an ajax update. The content only appears on the profile page once the background process is complete.

Thanks!

*Edited for clarification about ajax.*

Answer (score 0):

Capybara will re-check the existence of an element for 2 seconds until it gives up and throws an error.  See excerpt from docs (https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)

> If clicking on the foo link triggers an asynchronous process, such as an Ajax request, which, when complete will add the bar link to the page, clicking on the bar link would be expected to fail, since that link doesn't exist yet. However Capybara is smart enough to retry finding the link for a brief period of time before giving up and throwing an error. The same is true of the next line, which looks for the content baz on the page; it will retry looking for that content for a brief time. You can adjust how long this period is (the default is 2 seconds)

You can increase this by adjusting the following setting:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
```

Comment: The issue is, I'm not updating the page with an ajax call. This task runs in the background (though it doesn't take long) and adds a message which will only appear when a user refreshes the profile page.

Comment: I would probably just throw a revisit into a loop that checks every couple of seconds with a max cap.

Comment: Is there a way to do that and catch the failure before it kills the test?